# One question of measure theory

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let in $[1,\infty]$ exist functions $f(x)$ and $g(x) = f^3$ . If $g$ is measurable, does this imply that $f$ is measurable?

Also, if $f$ is Lebesgue integrable, does this imply that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: And... what about your thoughts/tries/troubles related to this?

Comment: $f^3<c$ then $f < c^{1/3}$. Then f is measurable. It's correct?

Comment: The point is in the exponent 3 which is an odd number. For even numbers, this is not true.

Comment: what about integrable?

Comment: I assume that $f$ is real valued here and that $f^3$ stands for the function that sends $x$ to $f(x)^3$. If so then see the comment of Artur. Or are you talking about $f\circ f\circ f$ here? If $f$ and $g$ are measurable then so is $f\circ g$ (if this composition exists).

Comment: Its evident that this post contains "A question about measure theory" by looking at the tags. Maybe you should change the tittle to an informative one to make it more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

For measurability: indeed, it follows from the fact that $t\mapsto t^3$ has a continuous (hence Borel-measurable) inverse.

For integrability, we can take functions on $[1,2]$, which is not so different from $[0,1]$. We can construct a counter-example taking $f(x):=x^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha$ a well-chosen real number.

Comment: It is not correct counter-example, because $x^{-3 \alpha}$ is integrable

Comment: When $\alpha:=1/2$ it's not so clear.